# IFrames causes the Parent Page Postback

Tags: html, asp.net, iframe

I have a page with 5 Iframes, which i use to display different pages. The Parent page which has these IFrames, has a Postback event in the .VB page.

```
     Protected Overrides Sub local_pageload()

     End Sub
```

This gets Hit that 6 times, 1 due to its own and 5 times due to 5 iframes, i assume. This causes my client side code also to fire 6 times. I cannot afford this behavior. I have kept my IFrames style to Display None to begin with. Biut this too did not help. Is there a way by which i can stop the postbacks due to the Iframes in the Parent Page.

Due to business requirements, i cannot use just 1 IFrame.

Comment: try visibility:hidden instead display:none

Comment: Thank you, but it did not work.

Comment: @user2561997 try to keep runat='server' and set visbile=false

Comment: But if i do that, i will not be able to hide or unhide in javascript? In my app i can show only 1 iframe at a time, and hide rest, all this Client Side.